# Conditionally calling a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, angularjs-directive, dom-manipulation

Let me preface this by saying that I am new to Angular. I'm working on my first project with Angular right now and I've ran into a multi-day issue. The functionality I'm working on I could do with jQuery, but I would like to understand the Angular way.

I would like to have a set of elements bounce around the page (like an old screensaver, stupid I know). I have a directive that handles this pretty well.

```
cancerApp.directive('ngSlider', function() {
  return {
    scope: true,
    template: "<li class='ng-slider' ng-style='pos'>{{choice}}</li>",
    replace: true,
    controller: function($scope, $interval, $element) {
      $scope.pos = {
        top: 0,
        left: 0.
      };

      $scope.newPos = function() {
      $scope.h = window.innerHeight - 50;
      $scope.w = window.innerWidth - 50;
      $scope.pos.top = (Math.random() * $scope.h) + "px";
      $scope.pos.left = (Math.random() * $scope.w) + "px";
      }

    $interval($scope.newPos, 1000);

    }
  }
});
```

And I'm calling the directive like this:

```
<li ng-slider class="choices" ng-click="selected(choice)" ng-repeat="choice in momChoice">
    {{choice}}
</li>
```

My issue is that I would like the elements to stop moving when the user hovers over the element. And then (if possible) start moving again when the user hovers off of the element.

I've looked for online help and made several attempts at it. I've tried adding conditional statements in the directive, on the controller, and on functions called within ng-mouseenter and ng-mouseleave with mixed results.

I feel like I'm stuck thinking in jQuery. I would like to better understand how Angular handles these sorts of situations. Any ideas, solutions, or resources that can point me in the right direction are much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your exact could would be like below. As @tpie said its extended answer

**Directive**

```
cancerApp.directive('ngSlider', function() {
  return {
    scope: true,
    template: "<li class='ng-slider' ng-style='pos'>{{choice}}</li>",
    replace: true,
    controller: function($scope, $interval, $element) {
      $scope.pos = {
        top: 0,
        left: 0.
      };

      $scope.newPos = function() {
      $scope.h = window.innerHeight - 50;
      $scope.w = window.innerWidth - 50;
      $scope.pos.top = (Math.random() * $scope.h) + "px";
      $scope.pos.left = (Math.random() * $scope.w) + "px";
      }

      var interval = $interval($scope.newPos, 1000); 
      element.on('mouseenter', function(){
          if(interval)
            $interval.cancel(interval);
      })
      element.on('mouseleave', function(){
          interval = $interval($scope.newPos, 1000);
      })

    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Wow, I was so close so many times.  Thanks for the help! I didn't think I would be able to call something as simple as a cancel( ) function, so I was trying to switch classes and remove attr(s). Thanks again.

Comment: @figbomb don't forget to accept answer..you could accept answer of tpie/me

Comment: Accepting your answer b/c the key part was `if(interval)
            $interval.cancel(interval);
      })`

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the directives animation code in something like this

```
   $element.on('mouseenter', function() {
       //clearInterval here - stop the animation
   });
   $element.on('mouseleave', function() {
       //start the animation
   });
```

Comment: Thanks for the help tpie! I had done that exact thing but I didn't understand how to stop the animation. I was stuck trying to switch classes, remove the attr all together, and then add it back on another mouseenter. I was making it way too complicated obviously.